# PHP/ExtJS - Converting a String with a unicode back to it's original character

Tags: php

I have a web app (built using ExtJS) where I let users update their basic info. I don't have problems with most of the update routine. However, when I tried updating a user with an ñ in their name, the PHP changed this to the Unicode `u00f1`.

For example, I pass the name `Añana`, which PHP shows is `Au00f1ana`, where "u00f1" replaced "ñ".

I already tried setting the charset to utf-8, `htmlspecialchars`, `mb_convert_encoding`, `utf8-decode`, and `html_entity_decode`, but none worked.

What I did to get around this problem is to use `strpos` and `substr_replace` to just replace the utf code with the original character.

```
if(strpos($my_string, 'u00f1') !== FALSE){
    $start_index = strpos($my_string, "u00f1"); 
    $last_name = substr_replace($my_string, "ñ", $start_index, 5);
}
elseif(strpos($my_string, 'u00F1') !== FALSE){
    $start_index = strpos($my_string, "u00F1"); 
    $last_name = substr_replace($my_string, "Ñ", $start_index, 5);        
}
```

For more context, this is the store I use:
Ext.define('AppName.store.MyStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

```
    requires: [
        'AppName.model.model_for_store',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.writer.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            remoteFilter: true,
            remoteSort: true,
            storeId: 'MyStore',
            batchUpdateMode: 'complete',
            model: 'AppName.model.model_for_store',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                batchActions: false,
                api: {
                    create: 'folder/folder/create.php',
                    read: 'folder/folder/read.php',
                    update: 'folder/folder/update.php',
                    destroy: 'folder/folder/delete.php'
                },
                url: '',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    keepRawData: true,
                    messageProperty: 'message',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    writeAllFields: true,
                    encode: true,
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

And this is the start of the PHP file that gets triggered for update:

```
<?php
require_once('../db_init.php');
require_once '../lib/response.php';
require_once '../lib/request.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");  

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1');
define('REPLACE_FLAGS', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML);

class my_object{ 
    //..... variables
}

$request = new Request(array());

if(isset($request->params)){

    $array_r=$request->params;

    $inputData->last_name=($array_r->last_name);
    $inputData->first_name=($array_r->first_name);
    $inputData->middle_name=($array_r->middle_name);

}
else{
    //echo "Update of User failed";
    $res = new Response();
    $res->success = false;
    $res->message = "Update User Failed!";
    $res->data = array();
    print_r($res->to_json());
}
?>
```

And as a reference, here's my `Request.php` file

```
<?php

class Request {
    public $method, $params;

    public function __construct($params) {
       // $this->restful = (isset($params["restful"])) ? $params["restful"] : false;
        $this->method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
        $this->parseRequest();
    }

    protected function parseRequest() {

            // grab JSON data if there...
            $this->params = (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) ? json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data'])) : null;

            if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {
                $this->params =  json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data']));
            } else {
                $raw  = '';
                $httpContent = fopen('php://input', 'r');
                //print_r($httpContent);
                while ($kb = fread($httpContent, 1024)) {
                    $raw .= $kb;
                }
                $params = json_decode(stripslashes($raw));
                if ($params) {
                    $this->params = $params->data;
                }
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Although I've checked ExtJS's documentation, and for the `encode` property in the JSONWriter, it says:

```
Configure `true` to send record data (all record fields if writeAllFields is true) as a JSON Encoded HTTP Parameter named by the rootProperty configuration.
```

So my model data is being sent as a JSON Encoded HTTP Parameter, and the PHP is able to parse it because the rootProperty is `data`, which matches line 19 in my request.php file:

```
$this->params = (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) ? json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data'])) : null;
```

I think the `json_decode(stripslashes(...)) is the one causing` ñ` to be converted to the utf-8 equivalent, and the stripslashes removed the leading backslash we usually see with the utf-8.

I have a feeling there's a better way to write this that won't convert the `ñ` to utf-8.

Does anyone have a better solution to this one?

Comment: Take a step back. What makes you think PHP is replacing this character? Where are you seeing that, and after what operation? Try to narrow down exactly where it's happening, because it's definitely not something that "just happens" when you use PHP.

Comment: @IMSoP I logged the value from ExtJS before I ran the store.sync() command that calls the PHP Update script. Then I logged the value received by PHP and it showed the "converted" one.

Comment: For reference, you don't need all that code with strpos and substr_replace to do basic string substitution, there's a built-in str_replace function for that. To be clear, though, you shouldn't need to be replacing anything in this string, you have a bug somewhere else that you should fix. You need to think a lot more specifically than "JS" and "PHP"; *how* is the message being sent - as URL parameters? as JSON? using some library code that might be reformating it? And *how* is it being received - in $_GET? using some framework code? using json_decode?

Comment: It is being sent via POST as JSON iirc. I have object handlers. I'll update my question.

Comment: @IMSoP I updated my question. It turns out that the object I use to parse the data sent in by the front end uses `json_decode(stripslashes(...)` and I have a gut feel that this is where the `ñ` gets converted to the utf code, and the stripslash removed the leading backslash. I'll look into this right now and check if there will be any adverse security issues if I remove these.

Comment: Yep, that would do it, because JSON (regardless of what language you're using) represents non-ASCII with the syntax `\uXXXX`; see https://3v4l.org/E8smB Not sure what that `stripslashes` was there for, but it's definitely your problem.

Comment: @IMSoP I removed the `stripslashes` and it works. More details in my answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem was the `stripslash` in the `request.php` file.

When ExtJS sends the data through the Store, I use `encode`, which puts it as an encoded JSON parameter. Normally it wouldn't be a problem when the `request.php` file gets it and runs `json_decode`, given that there were no escaped special characters. The problem is when I hit the `ñ`, it was converted to `\u00f1`, and the leading slash was trimmed. `json_decode` presumably did not recognize it again since there was no leading slash.

Major credits to IMSoP in the comments for the lead.